# MyBatis return value after Insert

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

Hey guys i am new to MyBatis and trying to create an account from incoming request object, but when i try doing it it says :

```
 Mapper method 'com.example.modular.mappers.AccountMapper.createAccount' has an unsupported return type: class com.example.modular.model.Account
```

Mapper :

```
public interface AccountMapper {

@Select("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE id = #{id}")
Account getAccount(@Param("id") Long id);

@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty = "id", keyColumn="id")
@Insert("INSERT INTO ACCOUNT(customerId,country) values (#{customerId},#{country})")
Account createAccount(Account account);
```

Sql schema
Regarding Schema i am not sure if first row where id specified i wrote correctly -> goal is for id to be auto incremented when new record gets inserted

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Account
(
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED always as identity,
    customerId  INTEGER,
    country  VARCHAR(22)

);
```

Account model

```
public class Account {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column("country")
    private String country;

    @Column("customerId")
    private Long customerId;

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218924/discussion-on-question-by-artjom-prozorov-mybatis-return-value-after-insert).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below insert query

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO ACCOUNT(customerId,country) values (#{account.customerId},#{account.country})")
```